# How to sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^2$ WITHOUT induction?

Tags: summation, induction

Is there any way to prove that:
$$ 1^2+2^2+3^2+\ldots +n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
but WITHOUT using mathematical induction? (I don't know, maybe through some creative graphical demonstration?)

Comment: $f(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}, f(n)-f(n-1) = n^2, f(0) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a graphic proof by
[Man-Keung Siu, appeared in: Mathematics Magazine March, 1984](http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/proof-without-words-sum-of-squares-0)

Comment: This is very elegant.